# How to make abbrv styled bibtex references support linking to external pages without showing the URL explicitly

Tags: bibtex

I'm pretty new to LaTeX.

I'm trying to have my web references (`@online`) support hyperlinking to its URL, but without explicitly showing the URL in the reference section.

The only way I found it to work was by using `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` but it shows the URLs in the reference. I need it to look like `\bibliographystyle{abbrv}` but have the title of the reference act as HREF.

Just in case this is required to know: I'm using `\documentclass{sig-alternate}`

**To visually represent what I'm trying to achieve:**

```
@online{patient_treat_sim,
  author = {John Doe},
  title  = {Title of the Reference, 09 2015.},
  url    = {http://www.google.com}
}
```

**How it looks right now:**

[1] John Doe. Title of the Reference, 09 2015.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

[1]  [John Doe. Title of the Reference, 09 2015.](http://www.google.com)

Could anybody point me to the right direction on how to achieve this?